# Javafx CSS Parsing Error

Tags: java, css, parsing, javafx

Hello currently I am working on adding a css file to my application in order to customize the interface more. However I am experiencing an error while parsing the CSS file. The application still runs, but I would like to know if this error may cause problems in the future if I leave it and how do I fix it. Below is the error, CSS file and the import of the CSS file.

**Import**

```
mapScene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("mapScene.css").toExternalForm());
```

**CSS**

```
.label{
-fx-font-size: 20;
-fx-font: Times New Roman;
-fx-background-color: #FDFEFE;
}
```

**Error**

```
Oct 16, 2016 7:57:20 AM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:[*PC Location]/bin/gameaspects/mapScene.css: Expected '<number>' while parsing '-fx-font' at [3,17]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote the font name, since it contains spaces, and use `-fx-font-family`. When you have multiple values for `-fx-font` it is expecting the first to be the font size (hence it is expecting a number):

```css
.label {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
    -fx-font-family: "Times New Roman";
    -fx-background-color: #FDFEFE;
}
```

See the [JavaFX CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont) for details on font settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

mapScene.getStylesheets().add("/mapScene.css");

Also you have to use px in -fx-font-size

Like -fx-font-size :12px;

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem and returns the same error as before. Also it should be`\\mapScene.css` not `/mapScene.css`.

Comment: @AdamReni did you try using px in font.Also i run fx programs using /.its the same weather you use \\ or /.

Comment: I just ran the program and for me its fine.let me check